# HTML5 - invalid form because placeholder is not a Number

Tags: html, css

My empty input form for number gets an invalid color through my css, because the placeholder text is not a number, or what else is wrong?

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u35TJ/1/)

```
:invalid {
  border: 2px solid #ff0000;
 }
```

html

```
 <input type="number" placeholder="Sum" required pattern="[0-9]*"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the placeholder but the required flag that makes the input light up red.
If you remove the required keyword it'll show up just fine.